# Why can't I move an element into vector of non-copyables?

Tags: c++, vector, move-semantics

The compiler tells me I'm trying to access a deleted function (i.e. the copy constructor of a lambda expression).  But I don't see where.

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> tasks;
std::packaged_task<int()> task{ [] { return 1; } };
tasks.emplace_back(
    [ t = std::move(task) ] () mutable { t(); });
```

([code is also here](http://cpp.sh/62hhm))

(I'm trying to find out why they use `shared_ptr<task>` in https://www.slideshare.net/GlobalLogicUkraine/c11-multithreading-futures).

On Gcc and MSVC I get the same error - I fear I'm doing something wrong...

```
error: use of deleted function 
'main()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const main()::<lambda()>&)'
```

Why can't I emplace this `std::function` onto the vector?

Comment: [How to store non-copyable std::function into a container?](/questions/28208948/how-to-store-non-copyable-stdfunction-into-a-container)

Comment: @cpplearner thanks, so it all boils down to `function` dictating CopyConstructable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function):

> F must meet the requirements of Callable and CopyConstructible

Where `F` is the function type used to construct the `std::function`. However,  `std::packaged_task` is [not copy constructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task). Thus in the capture list, `t` is not copy constructible, and is a non-static member of the lambda, making the implicit copy constructor for the lambda deleted.

Comment: I understand the not-copy-constructible, but.... but... I don't _want_ to use the copy constructor.  Why does `emplace_back([t]{})` need a copy constructor?

Comment: Ah!  It is the `function(F)` constructor that's being called, since I'm `emplace`ing a lambda!  That, I understand.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Lambdas and `std::packaged_task` are not `std::function`s.

Long answer, you cannot move a `std::packaged_task`  into a `std::function`

Here's what I'm offering as a solution:

```
std::vector<std::packaged_task<int()>> tasks;
std::packaged_task<int()> task{ [] () mutable { return 1; } };
tasks.emplace_back( std::move(task) );
```

If you actually need a std::function, and not just any callable, you'll have to bind a lambda into a `std::function`

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `std::function` requires the passed function object to be `CopyConstructible`, but `std::packaged_task<F>` is not (for any `F`). `std::function` performs *type erasure* where the dynamic type is not visible in the static type. Consider e.g.:

```
int invoke(std::function<int()> f) { return f(); }

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> p{/*etc*/};
    auto l = [] { return 5; };
    std::function<int()> f( /* either p or l */ );
    std::cout << invoke(f) << '\n';
}
```

The call to `invoke` requires copying `f` (pass by value). However, `f` is copyable if it has been made from `l`, but not copyable if it has been made from `p`, and this has nothing to do with the static type of `f`. There are basically three approaches to this problem:

- Forbid copying of `std::function` at compile time.
- Allow copying `std::function` at compile time, but throw a run time error if the contained type is not copyable.
- Allow copying `std::function` at compile time, and require any function object that you put into it to be copyable.

Approach #1 is very restrictive on how functions may be stored, passed and shared, and basically forbids common use cases in favor of the uncommon case of using a non-copyable function object.

Approach #2 is problematic because users would need to be educated that copying a `std::function` may fail in some cases and use great diligence when writing their code. Also, if the design requires sharing functions they may need to be wrapped in a `std::shared_ptr`. And if they need to be copied and may be stateful, it becomes even worse.

No matter how you view approach #3, it is the one that was standardized. But in light of the above-mentioned problems, it is also easily to defend.

As a matter of fact, I have written a `unique_function` class template that uses approach #1 for my current project because for us the use case of storing non-copyable asynchronous task objects is quite common, and copying or sharing such a task isn't necessary.